# detection of phosphorus in organic compound

Tags: organic-chemistry

I searched on internet and I don't find any elaboration of " detection of phosphorus " by chemical equation please elaborate it with chemical equations

Comment: Are you asking for a chemical reaction that would detect phosphorus within an organic compound? Or would any analytical technique suffice?

Comment: I,m asking about chemical reaction (equations)  that shows complete test to detect P in a organic compound...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check whether phosphorus is present in the organic compound or not:

The organic compound is treated with sodium peroxide($\ce{Na2O2}$). Phosphorus gets converted to sodium phosphate. Then we carry out the same procedure that we do to identify phosphate anion.

The aqueous extract is heated with concentrated nitric acid and ammonium molybdate. A canary yellow precipitate of ammonium phosphomolybdate is obtained. This yellow precipitate helps us conclude that Phosphorus was present in the organic compound.

Reactions:

$$\ce{Na3PO4 + 3HNO3 ->H3PO4 +3NaNO3}$$

$$\ce{H3PO4 + 12(NH4)2MoO4 + 21HNO3 ->(NH4)3PO4.12MoO3 (yellow ppt.) + 21NH4NO3 + 12N2O}$$

[image]